# Rails: Pass params from view to controller (Dynamic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view consisting of table which is not created by a form. I need to pass parameters from a link_to object to the controller.

There is an onclick event which increases the number of parameters on each click. All those parameters needs to be passed to the controller.

Is there a way to do so. I just need to pass each all the parameter that is collected in a local storage variable to controller.

I was able to work it around by adding ids as a query string such as:

```
/books/?ids=4,5,6,7,8
```

The above url was formed by changing the href attribute of link_to button each time an id is added to the local storage. But I do not want the ids to be visible to the user. Therefore finding out a way to pass params to controller.

Code for the button to which I need to pass params to my controller:

```
<div class="row"> <%= link_to "BooksInfo", books_path, class: 'btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light compare-btn pull-right' %> </div>
```

My Local Storage in which I'm storing the ids:

```
localStorage["bookID"]
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @31piy I have updated my code

Comment: If you don't want to reveal the params to the user in the URL, you will have to use an AJAX POST or form submit action.

Comment: But the page needs to be redirected to another page. So would the AJAX call work?

Comment: Did you consider using a form with a hidden field instead of the query parameters?

Comment: No, it won't redirect. Consider using form submit with hidden fields or so as @spickermann suggested.